# Elasticfox で EC2 に SSH ログイン する際の ${keyname} が文字列に展開されない

Tags: aws, firefox

Amazon EC2の管理に[Elasticfox](https://github.com/cookpad/elasticfox-ec2tag)を使っています。
Elasticfox から「Connect to Instance」操作で EC2 インスタンスに SSH ログインできて便利に使っていました。SSH クライアントは TeraTerm です。

EC2 インスタンスのキーペアを複数使い分け始めたので
SSH ログインするたびにTeraterm のパラメータを書き換えていますが
毎回設定を変えるのは面倒なので ${keyname} 変数を使いたいと思っています。

EC2 の「key name」には「mydemo」というキーペア名が設定されており
「${keyname}」と書いた部分が「mydemo」に置き換わることを期待しました。

しかし 実際には 置き換わらず SSL ログインが失敗します。

設定内容や使い方が間違っているのでしょうか。
${keyname} を使って自動ログインに成功している人がいたらアドバイスをお願いします。

◆Elasticfox の設定

```
SSH Command: E:\Program Files (x86)\teraterm\ttermpro.exe
SSH Arguments: /ssh2 /auth=publickey /keyfile=C:/key/${keyname}.pem /user=${user} ${publicDnsName}:22
```

---

また、次のようなバッチファイルを使って Elasticfox からどのような引数が渡されるか確認した所 ${key} や ${pass} も文字列に展開されていないことが分かりました。

◆バッチファイル

```
arg.bat
@echo off
for %%f in (%*) do (
  echo %%f
)
pause
```

◆バッチを呼び出すよう Elasticfox の設定を返る

```
SSH Command: c:\tool\arg.bat
SSH Arguments: home:${home} keyname:${keyname} host:${host} publicDnsName:${publicDnsName} privateDnsName:${privateDnsName} privateIpAddress:${privateIpAddress} ipAddress:${ipAddress} name:${name} key:${key} user:${user} pass:${pass}
```

◆実行結果

```
home:C:\Users\take88
keyname:${keyname}
host:***.***.***.***
publicDnsName:ec2-***-***-***-***.************.compute.amazonaws.com
privateDnsName:ip-***-***-***-***.************.compute.internal
privateIpAddress:10.1.2.3
ipAddress:***.***.***.***
name:demoserver
key:${key}
user:ec2-user
pass:${pass}
続行するには何かキーを押してください . . .
```